# DNS behind NAT (PowerDNS)

Tags: domain-name-system, firewall, routing

I'm having two different locations for DNS servers. I'm using PowerDNS. Locally everything works fine, but when I want to update from the Master the update over Internet is not working. 
I'm using on one location a software firewall PfSense, on the other location I have a PowerEdge 8 Pro router/firewall. Ports are OK and I can reach every server over port 53 (via for example Telnet) UDP and TCP.

When I look in the logging to see what is happening I see that the public IP address (which is x.x.x.82) is not reaching the second location. So I added the gateway address (which is x.x.x.77). This address is reaching the second location but I can't update because of the error that this 77 address is not a master. That is correct. It should be 82. I configured both addresses at the slave, but still without results. 
Does anyone have the same problem and/or does someone have a solution for it?

Comment: missing configuration of dns server

Comment: I do not follow your third paragraph at all (starting "When I look..."). Could you please rephrase it?

Comment: Hi Daniel, thanks for your comment. What I mean is the logging of the slave. The masters public address is x.x.x.82 and the publicaddress for the gateway of this subnet is x.x.x.77. There is no connection to the slave from the 82 address but there is from the gateway. But the gatewayaddress is ofcourse not the address from the master dns. And I can only allow the address from the master dns. How can I add a file to this post?